# How to new & delete AVPacket?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, memory-leaks

I'm working with a FFmpeg project right now, I have to store the data of `AVPacket` which from `av_read_frame`, and fill data to new `AVPacket` for following decoding.

Here is my problem: when I try to new & free an `AVPacket`, memory leaks always happen.

I am just doing a simple testing:

```
for(;;) {
    AVPacket pkt;
    av_new_packet(&pkt, 1000);
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    av_free_packet(&pkt);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read the FFmpeg 2.2 `AVPacket.c` source code.

```
int av_new_packet(AVPacket *pkt, int size) {
    AVBufferRef *buf = NULL;
    int ret = packet_alloc(&buf, size);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;

    av_init_packet(pkt);
    pkt->buf      = buf;
    pkt->data     = buf->data;
    pkt->size     = size;
#if FF_API_DESTRUCT_PACKET
FF_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
    pkt->destruct = dummy_destruct_packet;
FF_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#endif

    return 0;
}

void av_init_packet(AVPacket *pkt) {
    pkt->pts                  = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
    pkt->dts                  = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
    pkt->pos                  = -1;
    pkt->duration             = 0;
    pkt->convergence_duration = 0;
    pkt->flags                = 0;
    pkt->stream_index         = 0;
#if FF_API_DESTRUCT_PACKET
FF_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
    pkt->destruct             = NULL;
FF_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#endif
    pkt->buf                  = NULL;
    pkt->side_data            = NULL;
    pkt->side_data_elems      = 0;
}
```

I don't really know about the defines `FF_API_DESTRUCT_PACKET`, `FF_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS`, `FF_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS`

Some reason makes destruct of `av_free_packet` leak

According the source code, `av_init_packet` is called in `av_new_packet` and `av_new_packet` already allocates the `AVBuffer`, so if you want to set the data to new `AVPacket`.

Just memory copy to data of `AVPacket`, and call `av_free_packet` when you are done.

Answer (score 11):

- `av_new_packet` creates a packet and allocates data
- `av_init_packet`
  sets all packet members to default, and sets data pointer to `NULL`,
  the leak is here
- `av_free_packet` clears all visible members, but
  your data is already leaking

If you want FFmpeg to allocate the data for you, do not call `av_init_packet`. If you want to handle the data yourself, allocate the packet object on the stack and set its data yourself (and free it yourself):

```
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);
pkt.data = dataBuffer;
pkt.size = dataBufferSize;
// use your packet
// free your dataBuffer
```

Comment: Maybe things have changed now, since docs https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavc__packet.html#gac9cb9756175b96e7441575803757fb73 say "Note, this does not touch the data and size members, which have to be initialized separately."

Comment: No, it have not changed. I think there is a misunderstansing. I was refering to the data leaking, but not the `data` member. To be more precise, the the "data pointer" name that is leading is called `buf`. It is this member that is set to NULL in the init() function, thus not released in the free() function. The `data` member is only set to point to a member or this `buf` member. (see the av_new_packet code posted in the accepted answer for a clearer understanding)